# PHP Include = AJAX?

Tags: php, html, ajax

I think this will be quite a stupid question, but is the PHP include comparable to AJAX? Because I made a little page in which i load the contents via one index.php in which i have a pages array with every content page. And when I click on a link in the nav it seems to dynamically get the content, rather than reloading the page.

Can someone explain me, where the difference between AJAX and include is? Or is include in fact reloading the page rather than "swapping" contents?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is the PHP include comparable to AJAX

No.

Ajax is the process of making an HTTP request from JavaScript without leaving the current page.

A PHP include just includes some content (and may run some PHP) when the page initially loads.

> And when I click on a link in the nav it seems to dynamically get the content, rather than reloading the page.

If that happens, it isn't because of an include.

The most you could get from an include is to load a complete new HTML document which has some content that is identical to the previous HTML document.

If the page loads very quickly then the user might not notice the whole page reloading, but it will still do that.

Comment: Ah, the second part was what I was searching for. So I guess php include + Ajax will be the best solution for a neat document structure + dynamic website

Comment: Not necessarily. The benefits of avoiding loading a whole new page are, IMO, usually overrated (especially when compared to the cost of making a more complex Ajax solution, even more so if you do a robust `pushState` based version with server side fallback).

Comment: So you wouldn't recommend using AJAX at all?

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using it willy nilly. I wouldn't usually recommend it for doing basic navigation on a website. It's a tool, and it has its place. It's also fashionable, so it gets used in lots of places where there isn't really any benefit.

Comment: stop feeding the [help vampires](http://slash7.com/2006/12/22/vampires/)

Comment: @NDM rude... :D I can learn a lot by myself, but I didn't know this thing. Thank you Quentin